# Records as Prop?

Tags: coq

I just learnt that 'record' keyword can be used to define a Prop type, for example in:

```
Record Equivalence (A : Type) (R : relation A) : Prop := Build_Equivalence
  { Equivalence_Reflexive : Reflexive R;
    Equivalence_Symmetric : Symmetric R;
    Equivalence_Transitive : Transitive R }
```

But when I tried to define a Proposition using Record, as in:

```
Record proprecord : Prop := Build_proprecord
{
 Baa : nat; 
 Boo : Prop
}.
```

I get the following message by Coq:

```
proprecord is defined
Baa cannot be defined because it is informative and proprecord is not.
[cannot-define-projection,records]
Boo cannot be defined because it is informative and proprecord is not.
[cannot-define-projection,records]
```

Can anyone explain what Coq is complaining about - and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only get projection functions (functions that take the whole record and return a single field, like `fst` and `snd` for `prod`) for fields whose types are in `Prop`, with the reason being that you can only get things in `Prop` out of a `Prop` (with some caveats around what is called [singleton elimination](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/core/inductive.html#empty-and-singleton-elimination)). So Coq is warning you that it can't write the functions `Baa : proprecord -> nat` or `Boo proprecord -> Prop`.

If you want your record to behave like the `exists` quantifier, you can safely ignore or silence these warnings.

You can squash types into `Prop` by using `inhabited`, so you could write

```
Record proprecord : Prop := Build_proprecord
{
 Baa : inhabited nat; 
 Boo : inhabited Prop
}.
```

and get projections `Baa : proprecord -> inhabited nat` and `Boo : proprecord -> inhabited Prop`, if that is what you want.

Comment: Could you explain the term 'projection functions'?

Comment: @Kaind see [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63710026/revisions), projection functions take the whole record and return a single field, like `fst` and `snd` do for `prod`.